# MySQL ERROR 1064 Can´t figure it out

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-error-1064

Out of all the tables properly created in the database, the one below, is driving me crazy, can´t get it!

I would greatly appreciate your help deciphering the error.

```
"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `content_pages`;", 

"CREATE TABLE content_pages (
  id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  category int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  title varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  page blob NOT NULL,
  page_type varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  display_in_theme int(5) NOT NULL default '0',
  html_header int(5) NOT NULL default '0',
  reads int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;",
```

ERROR REPORT:

```
Database Queries
Query: CREATE TABLE content_pages ( id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment, category int(10) NOT NULL default '0', title varchar(200) NOT NULL default '', page blob NOT NULL, page_type varchar(20) NOT NULL default '', display_in_theme int NOT NULL default '0', html_header int NOT NULL default '0', reads int NOT NULL default '0', PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE = MyISAM;
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'reads int NOT NULL default '0', PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE = MyISAM' at line 9
```

NOTE:

I tried removing the int (5)´s and int (10) references; did not work either.

Comment: `reads` is reserved word in mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 2):

`reads` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped by backticks.

```
`reads` int(10) NOT NULL default 0,
```

Comment: Much obliged Juergen ,